# Android TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR null

Tags: android, android-sensors

i have android application and i used sensors ,

when i tried to get TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR or TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR its returned on some device null ! and this is close my app , so i need to get this on all android device versions , this is my code please help .

this is my code ,

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
 mRotationVectorSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR);


        if (mRotationVectorSensor != null) {
            success = true;


        } else {
            mRotationVectorSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
            if (mRotationVectorSensor != null) {
                success = true;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR and TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR require a gyroscope. Not all devices have a gyroscope.